# How to 'enter' a certain switch-statement mode, when it depends on a given realm-setting?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, switch-statement

I am making several languages available in my app. 
I wish to make it in a way, where the the 'Language Settings-Btn" is on the opening VC. Default language will be english, but the user can change to other languages in the tableView accessed from this button.

My current attempt (and this might not be the smartest way to do this), is that I created a Realm class called Language and then I attached buttons to all the cells in the LanguageSettingTableView. When pressing one of the buttons (languages), the user changes the Language.diaryLanguage to be whatever the pressed button represents.

Then I sat up a switch-statement in e.g. my welcomeScreenVC, where I currently have four different cases; English, Spanish, Danish, German (just for starters).

So I want to set up an if-statement (I guess?) inside viewWillAppear, in which I state: if Language.diaryLanguage == "English" --> Present case .english, etc. But I can't seem to find out how to reach these different cases.

Here's my relevant code in the welcomeScreenVC:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

enum LanguageMode {
case english
case spanish
case danish
case german
 }

class WelcomeScreen: UIViewController  {

var getStartedBtn = UIButton ()
var informationBtn = UIButton ()
var seeAllDiariesBtn = UIButton ()
var languageSettingsBtn = UIButton ()

var currentLanguage = Language()
var mode: LanguageMode = .english

private func modeUpdate() {
    switch mode {

    case .english:
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Create new People Diary", for: .normal)
        informationBtn.setTitle("Read More", for: .normal)
        seeAllDiariesBtn.setTitle("See all People Diaries", for: .normal)
        languageSettingsBtn.setTitle("Language", for: .normal)

    case .danish:
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Lav ny People Diary", for: .normal)
        informationBtn.setTitle("Læs Mere", for: .normal)
        seeAllDiariesBtn.setTitle("Se alle People Diaries", for: .normal)
        languageSettingsBtn.setTitle("Sprog", for: .normal)

    case .spanish:
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Hace nuevo People Diary", for: .normal)
        informationBtn.setTitle("Lees Mas", for: .normal)
        seeAllDiariesBtn.setTitle("Mirra todos People Diaries", for: .normal)
        languageSettingsBtn.setTitle("Idiomas", for: .normal)

    case .german:
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Bla bla Bla", for: .normal)
        informationBtn.setTitle("Bla bla bla", for: .normal)
        seeAllDiariesBtn.setTitle("Bla bla", for: .normal)
        languageSettingsBtn.setTitle("Bla bla", for: .normal)
    }
 }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if currentLanguage.diaryLanguage == "English" {
    // Then present case .english ...
    } else if currentLanguage.diaryLanguage == "Danish" {
        // Present case .danish ...
    } else if currentLanguage.diaryLanguage == "Spanish" {
        // Present case .spanish ...
    } else if currentLanguage.diaryLanguage == "German" {
        // Present case .german ...
    } else {
        // present .english (pr. default)
    }

    modeUpdate()
}
```

I hope someone can tell me how to achieve this. 
Thanks upfront!

Comment: Why dont you use `localisation`. Will save you lots and lots of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I share iOSer's recommendation that [localisation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) would be a better solution to implement the functionality you described ([see this guide for a good starting point](https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started)), to answer your specific question on how to use the `switch` statement, you just need to update the variable to the value associated with the case that you'd like to perform.

```swift
enum Language {
    case english, french, german
}

var language: Language = .english

func generateGreeting() -> String {
    switch language {
        case .english:
            return "Hello!"

        case .french:
            return "Bonjour!"

        case .german:
            return "Guten Tag!"
    }
}

generateGreeting() // 'Hello!'

language = .french
generateGreeting() // 'Bonjour!'

language = .german
generateGreeting() // 'Guten Tag!'
```

Where your `enum` represents a value of a specific type, such as in your example where a `String` is associated, you can instead use this as the value of each case.

```
enum Language: String {
    case english = "English"
    case french = "French"
    case german = "German"
}

Language(rawValue: "English") // .english
```